# What is the difference between form and pattern in the documentation?

Tags: pattern-matching, documentation

In the documentation, I see the term *form* and the term *pattern*. For example, see `Cases` and `MatchQ` for both usages. What is the difference? And is there a reference?

Comment: I don't think there is anything deep here. It is clear in the `MatchQ` doc article that *form* is a synonym for *pattern*. I suspect that the choice of *form* rather than *pattern* simply reflects that the two articles were written by two different writers or one writer when that writer was in a different mood.